# Implement trait "Not" recursively

Tags: types, rust, operator-overloading, traits

I have a struct `Couple` in rust with a type parameter

I would like to implement an operation (`Not` in this case) on this `Couple<T>`:
If `T` implement `Not`, the negation of the couple is the couple of the negations.

```rust
use std::ops::Not;

struct Couple<T>(T, T);

impl<T> Not for Couple<T>
where
    T: Not,
{
    type Output = Self;

    fn not(self) -> Self {
        Couple(T::not(self.0), T::not(self.1))
    }
}
```

This code compile with other traits (such as Default::default) but not with the trait `Not`.

I get the error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:12:16
   |
5  | impl<T> Not for Couple<T>
   |      - this type parameter
...
12 |         Couple(T::not(self.0), T::not(self.1))
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found associated type
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
             found associated type `<T as Not>::Output`
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
7  |     T: Not + Not<Output = T>,
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why is it the case? How can I implement `Not` and other operation traits for `Couple`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implementing [`Not for T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Not.html) does not mean that it will necessarily return `T`. So you have to specify the [`Output`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Not.html#associatedtype.Output) type, by doing e.g. `Not<Output = T>`.

```rust
use std::ops::Not;

struct Couple<T>(T, T);

impl<T> Not for Couple<T>
where
    T: Not<Output = T>,
{
    type Output = Self;

    fn not(self) -> Self {
        Couple(T::not(self.0), T::not(self.1))
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to allow a different `Output` type, based on `<T as Not>::Output`, then you can do this instead:

```rust
impl<T> Not for Couple<T>
where
    T: Not,
{
    type Output = Couple<T::Output>;

    fn not(self) -> Self::Output {
        Couple(T::not(self.0), T::not(self.1))
    }
}
```

You can of course also simplify `Couple(T::not(self.0), T::not(self.1))` into `Couple(!self.0, !self.1)`.

Comment: @rambi note that this is a real difference, in particular the second version implements `Not` for eg. `Couple<&i32>` and the first one does not.